# How to invoke Ctrl + S by code in a Form?

Tags: save, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I need to invoke by code the control <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>,
It's possible?

Look like element.task(2839) for the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>.

Thanks all,

enjoy!

Comment: It just takes a few seconds to overwrite the task method of any form, put a breakpoint there, then open the form, Ctrl+S and then debug that the task id is 272.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look in `\Macros\Task`.  It's `#taskSave`.

As FH-Inway said, it's 272.

```
#Task
element.task(#taskSave)
```

Comment: But most likely you need to call `datasource.write` or `datasource.forceWrite(true)` depending on your requirements.